# App URL for +1 button

Tags: java, android, google-plus

How can I get URL to gogle play site for +1 button? That one:
[image]

Original adress doesn't direct to that. I mean something like that:

```
String URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.package.name";
mPlusOneButton.initialize(mPlusClient,
                URL , PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Could you give me some example google play app URL?

Comment: Are you trying to  vote up it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

https://market.android.com/details?id=my.package.name"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Standard link does work for some apps, for some doesn't. Market link works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski is your +1 button working fine or `greyed out`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace "my.package.name" with the id of your app.

For example:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tunein.player
```

This is the URL to TuneIn Radio on Google Play. TuneIn Radio has the app id: `tunein.player`

Does that sort of answer your question?